multiple lines selection in sed with custom delimiter, why do I need to escape twice?
What I want to do

I want to parse a file to remove all lines before and after given patterns A and B (excluding pattern A and B).
I also want to use a custom delimiter instead of /.

What I tried
Deleting lines
Inspired by this question, the following does give the expected output
'/A/,/B/{//!d}'

Replacing the delimiter
Now, I want to modify my answer to use another delimiter than /; let say | instead.
I would write the following
'\|B|,|F|{//!d}'

but this fails with the following error message
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unexpected `,'

Escaping the delimiter
Escaping the third | fixes my issue.
'\|B|,\|F|{//!d}'

The question
Why can't I freely replace the delimiter in this solution
'\|B|,|F|{//!d}'

such that I had to do that instead
'\|B|,\|F|{//!d}'


Because you need to tell sed you are using a different delimiter. This is not a "double" escape, you use a single escape for the first delimiter, as required.

I'm sorry but this is still unclear to me. I understand that I needed to escape the first delimiter | to define a new delimiter, but my question was specifically regarding the third delimiter. Why does this one need to be escaped unlike the second or fourth ?

There is no third delimiter. There are two regexps, so, you escape the FIRST delimiter in  each.

Perhaps you are confusing the substitution command with a regexp address. The substitution command takes the form s/LHS/RHS/ where the first,second and third delimiters must be the same (remember the first delimiter is preceded by an s by and therefore there can be no confusion as to what kind of command it is). Whereas the regexp address by default uses the / delimiter which announces it as such a command and in order to overrule the default needs an escape e.g. \#regexp#. A range takes the form of two regexp address separated by a ,. BTW remember the -n option and the use of p.

@potong This is it. Please let me know if you want to write the answer yourself or rather I write the answer myself to close the question.


why do I need to escape twice?

You do not escape anything, this is the syntax of sed language. The context address, which is part of sed language, has the syntax:
/<regexp>/

or
\C<regexp>C

where C is any single character. See for exmaple POSIX standard https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html  section Regular Expressions in sed:

In a context address, the construction "\cBREc", where c is any character other than <backslash> or <newline>, shall be identical to "/BRE/". If the character designated by c appears following a <backslash>, then it shall be considered to be that literal character, which shall not terminate the BRE. For example, in the context address "\xabc\xdefx", the second x stands for itself, so that the BRE is "abcxdef".

The \ is part of the context address expression syntax, so has to be everywhere where such address expression form is used. There is no "escaping", it is just part of the sed language syntax.
If you want to use two addresses with two context addresses and both of them addresses use the form with a custom delimiter, they just both have to be in the form of \C<regexp>C.

If it is no trouble, can you complete your answer to include a quick explanation regarding why the syntax of s|a|b| seemingly does not require the delimiter character to be reintroduced for the second pattern ?

sed was invented the way it is by Lee E. McMahon, or rather ed was invented the way it is by the prophet Ken Thompson. There is no particular "why", rather "it is what it is". POSIX in this case only standardizes existing sed implementations.
Quoting again from the POSIX spec:

[2addr]s/BRE/replacement/flags
Substitute the replacement string for instances of the BRE in the pattern space. Any character other than <backslash> or <newline> can be used instead of a <slash> to delimit the BRE and the replacement. Within the BRE and the replacement, the BRE delimiter itself can be used as a literal character if it is preceded by a <backslash>.


As @potong had realised in one of their comment, I was confused because of commands such as s|a|b|. Your answer explicitly describe the notion of "context address" which was what I was missing. If it is no trouble, can you complete your answer to include a quick explanation regarding why the syntax of s|a|b| seemingly does not require the delimiter character to be reintroduced for the second pattern ? Unless a better solution appear, I will accept this solution whether or not you complement it as I consider the question sufficiently answered.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -n '\|A|,\#B#p' file

Since this is a filter operation use the -n option, escape/quote the range delimiters and p print the result(s).
See my initial comment in question comments and this entry in the manual.
N.B. Choose alternative address delimiters wisely as using a regexp metacharater will preclude its use in a regexp e.g. using the | rules out the use of alternation.
